# Consuming Json in Play Framework

Tags: java, extjs, playframework

I try to run this code but I get a Null Exception.

Java Code :

```
public static void updateData(List<Users> users){ 
   for(Users u : users){ //Error 
      System.out.println(u.name); // Error 
   } 
}
```

Extjs Code :

```
proxy: { 
    type: 'ajax', 
    api: { 
        update: '/Application/updateData' 
    }, 
    reader: { 
        type: 'json', 
        root: 'users', 
        successProperty: 'success' 
    } 
  }
```

Json Array :

```
[{"name":"Ed","email":"a...@aa.com"},{"name":"Ez","email":"b...@bb.com"}]
```

So please tell how to bind json Array to Entity List on Play Framework 
1.2.2. 
Thanks ...

Answer (score 2):

You've specified `root: 'users'` in your reader's config. This means that JSON Array should look like this:

```
{users: [{"name":"Ed","email":"a...@aa.com"},{"name":"Ez","email":"b...@bb.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Gson :

```
List<User> userList = new Gson().fromJson(yourString, Users.class);
```

And have a Users class suitable for your JSON :

```
public class Users {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    ...
    //[Add your getter and setter]
    ...
}
```

For more information you can read the [GSON documentation](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)